# Is there a built-in way to convert a 1d array to a 2d Array inside IronPython

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, ironpython, reshape

I am looking for an easy way to reshape an 1D array in IronPython without the usade of NumPy / Scipy for .NET into a 2D Array

I tries to find something similar to Numpy´s 'reshape" function, but so far I did not succeed.

Thanks for your help,

Sebi